# Two interfaces with the same method

Tags: c#, class, interface, public, void

I have 2 interfaces

```
public interface I1
{
     void sayHello (); 
}

public interface I2 
{
     void sayHello (); 
}

// and my class that implements the two interfaces
public class C1: I1, I2
{
    void I1.sayHello () {}
    void I2.sayHello () {}
}
```

The problem is that I can not make them public or call them in another public method in C1

Comment: You can call them, but I would say that is a very bad system design. Two interfaces doing the same work does not seem right.

Comment: @brainlesscoder Correction: Two methods by the same name which can easily do different jobs.

Comment: @ClickRick .. Correction: Yes, definitely right, but they are implemented in the same class, same name and different jobs. Really?

Comment: It does depend where the interfaces are defined. If one comes from one third-party provider and the other comes from a different third-party provider, then you're limited as to your options, because the names are fixed by someone beyond your control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to perform a typecast to whatever interface you want, even inside your class. If you want to call your I2 method implementation, call it using a cast like this:

```
(this as I2).SayHello();
```

Outside your class, for example you have to write:

```
C1 x = new C1();
(x as I1).SayHello();
```

What you have it is a so called explicit interface method implementation and those methods are accesible only through their interfaces.

Comment: If you're going to use `as` to do the cast, then it's conceivable that you'll get a null reference exception if something breaks at a later date.  `((I1)x).SayHello()` will get a cast exception under that circumstance, which would be clearer when debugging.

Comment: Both type casts are not saving you from runtime exceptions and as you can see i am not holding a reference of an interface for later use.The only reason i would make your choice is maybe for performance reasons(direct cast in IL is a little more faster than "as" operator)

Comment: @GeorgeLica, `as` should only be used if there is a chance that the cast fails, and it should always be followed by a null check. `(foo as Bar).Baz` is an antipattern

Comment: @george The point is that a NullReferenceException is inherently harder to debug (when it crashes, unexpectedly, 3 years later) than a InvalidCastException.

Comment: I really don't want to open this subject( "as", "is" and null checks, wich is better, etc) I am a software dev for more than 10 years in c# and i know very well how to write even in MSIL whatever typecast you want, belive me or not. The point is that my code was a simple example i did not thinked about all this things.

Answer (score 3):

This is called explicitly implemented interface. Of course you can call those methods, but you have to retype your class instance to the correct interface first.

```
var c1 = new C1();
((I1)c1).sayHello();
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(v=vs.71).aspx